# User input is terminated only on Ctrl D, instead of newline

Tags: perl, input

While reading user input from my script running on Debian, I found that user input would be terminated only after pressing Ctrl-D, instead of after hitting Enter/Return key.

```
my $userchoice = <>;
```

For my script, I require the user to enter text and terminate it with the Return/Enter key. What could be causing this in my script?

**Could setting slurp mode earlier in my script be related to this?**

I had a look at perdoc, but couldnt find an explanation there.

```
sub InteractiveMenu {
    for my $key(0 .. $#desclist) {
        my $value = $desclist[$key];
        printf (" %-3s %-20s -> %-15s -> %-30s\n", $key, $desclist[$key], $iplist[$key], $filelist[$key] );
    }
    print "\nAvailable choices:\n";
    printf " (R)oot key installation [installs your public key to remote servers]\n";
    printf " (S)etup remote logging [sets up user account on remotes]\n\n";
    print "Choose a server to work on:\n"; 
    chomp(my $userchoice = <>);
}
sub ListRemotes {
    print "Listing remote servers from $Confile\n";
    open my $ReadHandle, "<", $Confile or die $!;
    local $/; # enable localized slurp mode
    chomp(my $content = <$ReadHandle>);
    close $ReadHandle;
    my @values = split('zone ', $content);
      foreach my $val (@values) {       
        #print $val."\n-------------------------\n";
        &ListWorker($val);
      }
    InteractiveMenu();  
}
```

[image]

Comment: What you've posted will read a single line terminated by a carriage return. It doesn't require Ctrl-D.

Comment: It will keep requesting user input until Ctrl-D is pressed, at least on my Debian bash shell.

Comment: Show your actual code.

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: I do have slurp mode set in the script. Could this cause the problem?

Comment: Yes. You've told the script not to use return as an input separator.

Comment: Thanks @Wooble. I added a sub for reading the file into a variable, and thus solved it by localizing slurp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could setting slurp mode earlier in my script be related to this?

Yes. Setting `$/` to undef causes `readline` (aka `<>`) to read until the end of the file instead of until the end of the line. Ctrl-D causes your terminal to signal EOF.

Comment: What's the proper way to reset it back after being done with slurp mode?

Comment: `local $/;` instead of `$/ = undef;` will cause it to get reset automatically at the end of the scope.

Comment: What I meant was-supposing one needs to use both slurp mode and line-by-line reading within the same scope, is there a way to reset it?

Comment: You can always do `$old_irs = $/; $/ = undef; ... $/ = $old_irs;`, but it's easier just creating a scope (`{ local $/; ... }`).

Answer (score 0):

To reset the slurp mode, you can put the slurp mode into a scope

```
open my $ReadHandle, "<", $Confile or die $!;
{
    local $/; # enable localized slurp mode
    chomp(my $content = <$ReadHandle>);
}
close $ReadHandle;
```